# Remote Code injection in Win 7 SP 1 using NtCreateThreadEx API

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7, code-injection, dll-injection

I am trying to learn how to inject code into a running process using NtCreateThreadEx. I found few tutorials online and tried the code shown below which basically tries to inject a piece of code to a a running notepad.exe. Code injection to notepad.exe was successful; however, this program crashes just after injection (i.e., after calling funNtCreateThreadEx) throwing following error:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'temp2' was corrupted.
```

Could someone help me explaining why I am getting this error? I tried to Google about this error and figured out its something related to memory overflow. However, I don't see any memory overflow in this following code. Please let me know what could be the reason for the above error. Thank you so much for your time.

```
HANDLE NtCreateThreadEx(HANDLE process, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE Start, LPVOID lpParameter);

typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI *LPFUN_NtCreateThreadEx)
(
    OUT PHANDLE hThread,
    IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
    IN LPVOID ObjectAttributes,
    IN HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    IN LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
    IN LPVOID lpParameter,
    IN BOOL CreateSuspended,
    IN DWORD StackZeroBits,
    IN DWORD SizeOfStackCommit,
    IN DWORD SizeOfStackReserve,
    OUT LPVOID lpBytesBuffer
    );

struct NtCreateThreadExBuffer
{
    ULONG Size;
    ULONG Unknown1;
    ULONG Unknown2;
    PULONG Unknown3;
    ULONG Unknown4;
    ULONG Unknown5;
    ULONG Unknown6;
    PULONG Unknown7;
    ULONG Unknown8;
};


HANDLE NtCreateThreadEx(HANDLE process, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE Start, LPVOID lpParameter) {

    HMODULE modNtDll = LoadLibrary(L"ntdll.dll");

    if (!modNtDll) {
        std::cout << "Error loading ntdll.dll" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    LPFUN_NtCreateThreadEx funNtCreateThreadEx = (LPFUN_NtCreateThreadEx)GetProcAddress(modNtDll, "NtCreateThreadEx");

    if (!funNtCreateThreadEx) {
        std::cout << "Error loading NtCreateThreadEx()" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    NtCreateThreadExBuffer ntbuffer;

    memset(&ntbuffer, 0, sizeof(NtCreateThreadExBuffer));
    DWORD temp1 = 0;
    DWORD temp2 = 0;


    ntbuffer.Size = sizeof(NtCreateThreadExBuffer);
    ntbuffer.Unknown1 = 0x10003;
    ntbuffer.Unknown2 = 0x8;
    ntbuffer.Unknown3 = &temp2;
    ntbuffer.Unknown4 = 0;
    ntbuffer.Unknown5 = 0x10004;
    ntbuffer.Unknown6 = 4;
    ntbuffer.Unknown7 = &temp1;
    // ntbuffer.Unknown8 = 0;

    HANDLE hThread;
    NTSTATUS status = funNtCreateThreadEx(
        &hThread,
        0x1FFFFF,
        NULL,
        process,
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Start,
        lpParameter,
        FALSE, //start instantly
        0, //null
        0, //null
        0, //null
        &ntbuffer
        );
    return hThread;
}

int main()
{
    int res = -1;
    res = privileges(); //get all required privileges

    DWORD pid = getPid(L"notepad.exe");

    if (pid == 0)
        return PROCESS_NOT_FOUND; //error

    HANDLE p;
    p = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pid);
    if (p == NULL) return OPEN_PROCESS_FAILED; //error


    char * mytext = "Hello by CodeCave!";
    char * mycaption = "Injection result";

    PARAMETERS data;   //let's fill in a PARAMETERS struct
    HMODULE user32 = LoadLibrary(L"User32.dll");
    data.MessageBoxInj = (DWORD)GetProcAddress(user32, "MessageBoxA");
    strcpy_s(data.text, mytext);
    strcpy_s(data.caption, mycaption);
    data.buttons = MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONQUESTION;

    //Writing funtion to notepad memory
    DWORD size_myFunc = 0x8000; //Creating more memory than required
    LPVOID MyFuncAddress = VirtualAllocEx(p, NULL, size_myFunc, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    WriteProcessMemory(p, MyFuncAddress, (void*)myFunc, 0x1000, NULL);

    //Parameters to the function to notepad's memory
    LPVOID DataAddress = VirtualAllocEx(p, NULL, sizeof(PARAMETERS), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    WriteProcessMemory(p, DataAddress, &data, sizeof(PARAMETERS), NULL);

    //invokes injected function
    HANDLE thread = NtCreateThreadEx(p, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MyFuncAddress, DataAddress);

    if (thread != 0) {
        //injection completed, not we can wait it to end and free the memory  

    }
    return 0;
}

static DWORD myFunc(PARAMETERS * myparam) {
MsgBoxParam MsgBox = (MsgBoxParam)myparam->MessageBoxInj;
int result = MsgBox(0, myparam->text, myparam->caption, myparam->buttons);
switch (result) {
case IDOK:
    //your code         
    break;
case IDCANCEL:
    //your code
    break;
}
return 0;
} 

int privileges() {
    HANDLE Token;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &Token))
    {
        LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &tp.Privileges[0].Luid);
        tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
        if (AdjustTokenPrivileges(Token, 0, &tp, sizeof(tp), NULL, NULL) == 0) {
            return 1; //FAIL
        }
        else {
            return 0; //SUCCESS
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

typedef int (WINAPI* MsgBoxParam)(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT);

struct PARAMETERS {
    DWORD MessageBoxInj;
    char text[50];
    char caption[25];
    int buttons;
};

DWORD myFunc(PARAMETERS * myparam);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the undocumented NtCreateThreadEx instead of the documented CreateRemoteThread?  (Best guess as to the cause of the crash: the structure of NtCreateThreadExBuffer or the signature of NtCreateThreadEx has changed, perhaps because the information you're using is for 32-bit systems and you're running on a 64-bit one.)